# Clustering in DataFrame using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, hierarchical-clustering

I have a dataset

```
Name    System
A       AZ
A       NaN
B       AZ
B       NaN
B       NaN
C       AY
C       AY
D       AZ
E       AY
E       AY
E       NaN
F       AZ
F       AZ
F       NaN
```

Using this dataset, I need to cluster the dataset based on the number of times "System" is repeated for a particular "Name".

In the above example, Names A, B and D have one "AZ" "Subset" while C, E have two "AY" subsets and F has two AZ so it is a different cluster.
We can ignore NaN.

Output Example:

```
Cluster     Names
AZ          A,B
AY,AY       C,E
AZ,AZ       F
```

How can I do it using Python?

PS. Actual dataset may vary in number of rows and columns
Also, how can I do it using ML based classification algorithms like KNN, Naive Bayes, etc?

Comment: In the above question, how can I form clusters without ignoring NaN values.

Answer (score 4):

Use `groupby` + `agg` twice; once to `join` "Systems" and then to `join` "Names":

```
s = df.dropna().groupby('Name').agg(', '.join)['System']
s = pd.Series(s.index, index=s)
out = s.groupby(level=0).agg(', '.join).reset_index().rename(columns={'System':'Cluster'})
```

Output:

```
  Cluster     Name
0  AY, AY     C, E
1      AZ  A, B, D
2  AZ, AZ        F
```

Comment: These work perfectly fine. Is there any ML based clustering way [eg. KNN] I can do this.

Comment: Can you please share the code for the same.

Comment: Sure, Please do share.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70966309/17778275

Answer (score 4):

If ordering per groups is same use double `groupby` by `Name` and then by `System` columns:

```
df1 = (df.dropna(subset=['System'])
         .groupby('Name')['System']
         .agg(','.join)
         .reset_index()
         .groupby('System')['Name']
         .agg(','.join)
         .rename_axis('Cluster')
         .reset_index())

print (df1)
  Cluster   Name
0   AY,AY    C,E
1      AZ  A,B,D
2   AZ,AZ      F
```

If ordering should be different, so sort values is necessary use:

```
df1 = (df.dropna(subset=['System'])
         .sort_values(['Name','System'])
         .groupby('Name')['System'].agg(','.join)
         .reset_index()
         .groupby('System')['Name']
         .agg(','.join)
         .rename_axis('Cluster')
         .reset_index())
```

Comment: These work perfectly fine. Is there any ML based clustering way [eg. KNN] I can do this.

Comment: @SHLOKDOSHI - I think is necessary post new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70966309/17778275
Please share here.